# removing White Spaces in String

Tags: java, regex

i have to get rid of **more than 1 space**  that is if there is more than 1 space i had replaced it with single space. This is how i did it but i am  really confused which is the best way to do it and what is difference in all these. below is my code:

```
     public class SspaceDemo {

public static void main(String[] as) {
    String s="  Hi this   space  Demo   ";

    String  s1 = s.replaceAll("\\s +", " ");
    System.out.println(s1.trim());
    String  s2 = s.replaceAll(" +", " ");
    System.out.println(s2.trim());
    String  s3 = s.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
    System.out.println(s3.trim());
}
}
```

which is the best way to achieve the result. please suggest.  Thanks,

Comment: Could you indicate if you really just want to replace spaces or all white space characters with a single space? Note that `\\s +` actually looks for any number >= 1 of white space characters, *followed by a single space* which is not what you might expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the best way.

```
   s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

**What does that \s+ mean?

\s+ is a regular expression. \s matches a space, tab, new line, carriage return, form feed or vertical tab, and + says "one or more of those". Thus the above code will collapse all "whitespace substrings" longer than one character, with a single space character.**

Answer (score 3):

You could use the method StringUtils.deleteWhitespace() from commons-apache.

@see http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#deleteWhitespace%28java.lang.String%29

Personnaly I would avoid regex usage for such purpose.

Have fun!

Comment: I would avoid deprecated methods (-1), and most of the time I would try to avoid braindead Apache API's too. Look at the samples in the `removeWhitespace` that should replace `deleteSpaces()` : they only shows spaces. And although the use of regexps is not without danger, I wonder how it compares with the inclusion of (yet another) library.

Comment: I changed to use the non-deprecated method -> deleteWhitespace(). In fact they do not use any regexp to remove those whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with `replaceAll(" {2,}", " ")`. I would also call `trim()` before calling `replaceAll`. These would result, I think, in the fewest actual replacements, which might have a (very) slight speed advantage.

However, they are all pretty much equivalent and unless you're doing this a *lot* in a tight loop, just pick one that works and go with it. If you're really concerned about performance, you should probably scan character-by-character yourself. It's a lot more programming work but will probably execute faster than the heavy-duty regular expression machinery involved with `replaceAll`.

Comment: I would use `"[ ]{2,}"` because it is the most concise and the square brackets makes it easier not to overlook the space character. Of course, you might as well use an escape like such: `"\\x20{2,}"`, which most experienced programmers should pick up easily. And I *always* add a comment before a regexp to indicate *what* I want to do, because it is tricky to extract that from a regexp, especially if it grows because of later additions.

Comment: @owlstead - Good points, especially about commenting the regexp! I don't want to think about all the time I've spent reverse engineering some regex I wrote and didn't document. Sometimes all it takes is an hour or two before it transforms from a wonderfully clever thing of beauty into what appears to be line noise.

Answer (score 2):

`"\\s +"` and `" +"` are a bit different: the first captures *any* whitespace (tabs, spaces are the main ones) followed by at least one space, while the second only captures spaces. As for `+` or `{2,}`, the latter may be a tad more efficient, but the former is more readable. I would prefer it.

Comment: No, it doesn't capture any whitespace, it captures any whitespace including the single space character that must be present at the end of the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think proper regex for search would be:

```
"\\s{2,}"
```

Comment: That depends on what Kmme83 wants to accomplish doesn't it? Why not ask before posting?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String removeExtraWhiteSpaces(String str){
        String myString = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
        return myString;
    }

    public static String removeAllWhiteSpaces(String str){
        String myString = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim();
        return myString;

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try with this

```
String str=s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: the question is NOT about removing non-printing characters.  It is about **replacing** sequences of *white-space* characters with a single space.